# Can I start a sentence with 'and'

Tags: style

Is it appropriate to start a sentence with 'and'? We like to do it in my language. It emphasizes that the action in the sentence is a continuation of the previous. And it makes the flow of ideas more softer.

> And they lived in paradise. And they were naked but not ashamed.

In my language if I start a sentence with 'and' I can omit the object. Because it is clear that the action happens with the previous object. Can I do it in English?

> **He** called me. *And* said that he would be late.

Comment: Off-topic, but "more softer" is wrong. "softer" or "more soft" (although the latter is inferior).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googling "start sentence with and or but" shows many links saying that this is perfectly acceptable, despite assertions to the contrary.  This is a nice explanation:

> There is a persistent belief that it is improper to begin a sentence with And, but this prohibition has been cheerfully ignored by standard authors from Anglo-Saxon times onwards. An initial And is a useful aid to writers as the narrative continues.
>   - From The New Fowler's Modern English Usage

While it's considered a bit informal, it's perfectly acceptable.